# pandas timeseries compute mean and delta of subsets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm dealing with timeseries data. Basically, what I'm trying to do is to calculate the delta between the mean speeds each time the Status changes from "SR_OPEN" to "SR_CLOSE".

extract1:

```
                        speed       Status  count1  count2
Zeitstempel                 
2018-01-18 09:17:00     103.552239  SR_OPEN     0   1.0
2018-01-18 09:18:00     116.066667  SR_OPEN     0   2.0
2018-01-18 09:19:00     106.958904  SR_OPEN     0   3.0
2018-01-18 09:20:00     109.057971  SR_OPEN     0   4.0
2018-01-18 09:21:00     110.737705  SR_OPEN     0   5.0
2018-01-18 09:22:00     108.525424  SR_CLOSE    1   6.0
2018-01-18 09:23:00     109.568627  SR_CLOSE    2   7.0
2018-01-18 09:24:00     106.698113  SR_CLOSE    3   8.0
2018-01-18 09:25:00     104.500000  SR_CLOSE    4   9.0
2018-01-18 09:26:00     93.285714   SR_CLOSE    5   10.0
```

extract2 (dataset):

```
                       speed        Status  count1  count2
Zeitstempel                 
2018-01-19 07:50:00     123.551724  SR_OPEN     0   1.0
2018-01-19 07:51:00     113.947368  SR_OPEN     0   2.0
2018-01-19 07:52:00     115.527273  SR_OPEN     0   3.0
2018-01-19 07:53:00     113.028986  SR_OPEN     0   4.0
2018-01-19 07:54:00     113.309091  SR_OPEN     0   5.0
2018-01-19 07:55:00     93.467532   SR_CLOSE    1   6.0
2018-01-19 07:56:00     94.718310   SR_CLOSE    2   7.0
2018-01-19 07:57:00     103.835443  SR_CLOSE    3   8.0
2018-01-19 07:58:00     113.275862  SR_CLOSE    4   9.0
2018-01-19 07:59:00     113.791045  SR_CLOSE    5   10.0
```

I know how to extract the intervalls of those situations "globally" and compute the median:

```
# median speed 1-5 mins before closing:
df1=df.loc[(df.Status == 'SR_OPEN')&(df.count1 == 0)&(df.count2 >= 1)&(df.count2 <= 5)]
df1.speed.median()

# median speed 1-5 mins after closing:
df2=df.loc[(df.Status == 'SR_CLOSE')&(df.count1 >= 1)&(df.count1 <= 5)]
df2.speed.median()
```

However, I would like to calculate the mean of the speeds (i.e. 5 intervals) EACH TIME before and after the status changes from "SR_OPEN" to "SR_CLOSE" and then compute the delta of those mean speeds. Any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: Iterate condition status column with operation on speed columns.

Comment: okay...using iterrows? It's a bit tricky for me .. I havent used loops much with Pandas.. :/

Comment: Yes. after change in status you have to pick 5 from open and 5 from close right?

Comment: Yes - pick 5 from open and calculate mean, then pick 5 from close and calculate mean. Then calculate difference of those means. Maybe you can help out with some code? :/